# How to create click event for navigation drop down using html helper class?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-helper

I am using MVC 5. I have created navigation drop down. This is my code:

```
            <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="menu">
                Report
                <b class="caret"></b>
            </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">

            <li class="myselector"><a href="#">a </a></li>


            <li><a href="#">b </a></li>


            </ul>
            </li>
```

Now I have same controller but different actions for a and for b.

How to move to another page while click a and b. Is there any click event available?

Comment: why don't you use the helper methods in the cshtml file to generater the paths accordingly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it work with some js code, but you does not attach any js here. So, you need to add something to your html code for identify your links as different links.
Something like this

```
<li class="myselector action-show-a"><a>A</a></li>
<li class="myselector action-show-b"><a>B</a></li>
```

Then you need to select your elements using .myselector and add to them specified action according to .action-show-a and .action-show-b. For this purpose you need to add eventlistners to onclick actions.